# Determining Categorical vs. Numerical Data in CSV File --

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV (Comma Separated Value) file that has a mixture of categorical, and numerical data.

I would like to be able to determine whether the data is either categorical or numerical, so I can programatically plot the data in a scatter plot that I created in Swing.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in Java? I'm looking for approaches--not code.

Comment: Sure, you have the following columns: Name, Region (Categorical -- N, E, W, S), Income (Numerical - $0 - $10000), Population (Numerical)

Answer (score 1):

**Use `Double.parseDouble()` or `Integer.parseInt()` to check for numerical data.**

Both methods take a `String` as an argument and return a `double` or an `int` primitive. These methods will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the string you pass is not numerical.

I see that you have fixed column ordering, as described in your comment.  In this case, you already know which data is numerical and which is categorical by its position in the line.  So only be sure to parse numerical values on the columns that expect numerical values.  If you catch this exception, it means your data file is malformed or you have a bug in your parsing logic.  Of course, you have to strip out the dollar sign.

Comment: I believe this is wrong. eg. pin code it should be treated as category not numeric. So you can identify this using your domain knowledge.

Comment: If you wanted to look at the data and determine its type from the data, a pin number would appear numerical.  This is a problem with not knowing your data, but it doesn't make this answer incorrect if you wished to imply the data type from the data.  I event commented in my answer that OP should already know which column should contain numerical data, so that it might be processed correctly.